# Is it common to have multiple recessive traits in humans?

Tags: human-genetics

I just started thinking about my phenotype and realized I got multiple recessive traits. I have attached ear lobes, my blood type is O-, I got green eyes (I think eye color in polygenic but still somewhat recessive), a few years back I was in the control group of a study that was looking for a link between an allelic variant and the development of diabetes mellitus in patiences with another disease I forgot which, I was the only homozygous among all control patients! so you get the point. I am just wondering if anyone has any notion of how often humans present multiple recessive traits, maybe in terms of allelic frequency or something like that, or where can I find information about it. And maybe if there is something health related that may be worth knowing. I mean apart from a minor allergy I'm a really healthy person, but I may have predisposition to something.

Comment: Depends on the allele frequency in the population.

Comment: sure, but I guess my question is if there is some database where I can look at some actual numbers...

Comment: Think of law of independent assortment and gene linkage.

Answer (score -1):

It depends on how long a population in your dominant heritage was genetically isolated, how common certain recessive traits are.

However, you might reconsider about the "green eyes".  Iridologists claim that there are only blue eyes, and light brown eyes.  All other colours are indicative of bioaccumulation of various substances (evidenced by a return to blue or light brown when the body is supported in excreting these substances), and health issues in certain tissues.

While there is argument about how scientific a technique iridology is, all medicine begins as observation of patterns, and development of models based on those patterns.  Models in medicine are constantly undergoing upgrading and replacement, as old models no longer explain new and well-observed patterns.

Comment: Please support some evidence for the claim that some eye colours are caused by bioaccumulation of substances **and** that the body can be supported to get rid of those substances and eye colour changes can be caused by that.